# Understanding AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am trying to understand how things work when one writes the following in `settings.py`:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
    "master_password.auth.ModelBackend"
)
```

In particular, the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends) states:

> If a backend raises a `PermissionDenied` exception, authentication will immediately fail. Django won’t check the backends that follow.

Given this, how can the second and the third backend in the above example get a chance when a user has entered an incorrect password and the first backend has denied him access? More specifically, the third backend pertains to [django-master-password](https://pypi.org/project/django-master-password/), which should let the user in if he used a master password even if it does not match the user's password. So, how will that backend ever get a chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [**`docs`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-authentication-backends):

> Django tries authenticating across all of its authentication backends. If the first authentication method fails, Django tries the second one, and so on, until all backends have been attempted.

`django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend` (if I recall correctly) does not raise `PermissionDenied`, so if authentication fails on it, the succeeding authentication backends will be used until a match is found.

> The order of AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS matters, so if the same username and password is valid in multiple backends, Django will stop processing at the first positive match.

If you find that it does raise `PermissionDenied`, then that model backend would probably be better placed at the end of your `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` list.